# Why does the Earth not spiral into the Sun if it is charged?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, charge, solar-system

The Rutherford Model of the atom was similar to the solar system. The major drawback of the model was that it was not consistent with maxwell's theory of electromagnetism which stated that :
All charged accelerated particles emit electromagnetic radiation.
The electrons were charged and were accelerated due to their circular motion around the nucleus which meant that they lost energy and hence their orbit will shrink and it will spiral into the nucleus.
Now if we apply this analogy to the solar system. If the earth is uncharged, there should be no problem, but if it is charged, then why does it not spiral into the sun, given that the electric forces are much stronger than the gravitational forces (The sun is also charged). So my question why is the Earth stable, even though it is charged.
[http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/~mcintyre/COURSES/ph431_F12/examples/EarthCharge.pdf](http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/%7Emcintyre/COURSES/ph431_F12/examples/EarthCharge.pdf)

Comment: Also note that the presence of an electric field between the earth's surface and its upper atmosphere does not mean that the earth and its atmosphere *together* have an overall net charge - it simply means that there is an uneven distribution of positive and negative charge.

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation of the effect?

Comment: To be clear, the Rutherford model applies to having a small massive nucleus holding the positive charges (and, it turned out, neutrons as well). The Bohr model introduced the concept of electron orbitals around the nucleus, which led to the correct interpretation using the Schrodinger equation. Rutherford said nothing about electron orbitals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Earth as a whole is electrically neutral while thunderstorms creat the atmospheric charge maintaining it at approximately 300 kV, that discharges slowly. The process is confined to earth's atmosphere and the earth's surface and thus the electrostatic force does not contribute in providing earth's its motion around the sun.